# DTD - attributes with fixed default values

Tags: xml, dtd

Lets say I have a snippet of a DTD declaration like this.

```
<!ELEMENT book ANY>
<!ATTLIST book genre #FIXED "fantasy">
```

Note that the `genre` attribute was declared with a fixed default value of `fantasy`.

What exactly is the meaning of such a declaration? Two possible interpretations come to mind:

1. A document is not valid unless each `book` element contain a `genre` attribute with value `fantasy`.
2. A document is valid if each `book` element either contains a `genre` attribute with value `fantasy` or does not contain the `genre` attribute at all.

I did not find a definitive answer in [the DTD specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/), even though the second one seems more likely because of the following part:

> Validity constraint: Fixed Attribute Default
>
> If an attribute has a default value declared with the #FIXED keyword,
>   instances of that attribute MUST match the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpretation 2 is the correct one. Demonstration:

#### DTD (fixed.dtd)

```
<!ELEMENT root ANY>

<!ELEMENT book ANY>
<!ATTLIST book id ID #IMPLIED
               genre CDATA #FIXED "fantasy">

<!ELEMENT magazine ANY>
<!ATTLIST magazine id ID #IMPLIED>
```

#### XML 1

```
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "fixed.dtd">
<root>
  <book id="ID01" genre="fantasy"/>
  <magazine id="ID02" />
</root>
```

xmllint output:

```
$ xmllint --postvalid fixed.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "fixed.dtd">
<root>
  <book id="ID01" genre="fantasy"/>
  <magazine id="ID02"/>
</root>
```

#### XML 2

```
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "fixed.dtd">
<root>
  <book id="ID01"/>
  <magazine id="ID02" />
</root>
```

xmllint output:

```
$ xmllint --postvalid fixed.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "fixed.dtd">
<root>
  <book id="ID01"/>
  <magazine id="ID02"/>
</root>
```

#### XML 3

```
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "fixed.dtd">
<root>
  <book id="ID01" genre="crime"/>
  <magazine id="ID02" />
</root>
```

xmllint output:

```
$ xmllint --postvalid fixed.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "fixed.dtd">
<root>
  <book id="ID01" genre="crime"/>
  <magazine id="ID02"/>
</root>
fixed.xml:3: element book: validity error : Value for attribute genre of book is different from default "fantasy"
fixed.xml:3: element book: validity error : Value for attribute genre of book must be "fantasy"
Document fixed.xml does not validate
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that xmllint adheres fully to the specification? Isn't there a possibility that xmllint has this implemented in a wrong way?

Comment: I get the same results with Oxygen XML Editor (which uses Java libraries for validation).

Comment: No, I don't suspect anything wrong. I just tend to be careful as, from my experience with tools that do not conform fully to the specifications, the fact that a specific implementation works some way shouldn't alone be regarded as a proof that the way is correct according to the specification. But in this case I am inclined to explain the specification in this way as well, so it seems to be correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The second one is true! In effect the attribute can not declarate in XML.